# Known issues/complications for upgrading code using the Tridion Business Connector from 2009 to 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

Are there any known issues/complications for migrating code that is using the Tridion Business Connector during a Tridion 2009 to 2011 SP1 upgrade?

I know that the migration from R5.3 may cause problems because of the fact that Categoies & Keywords are now hierarchical.  Are there any likely to be any simillar issues with an upgrade from 2009 to 2011 SP1?

**I understand that the Business Connector is deprecated, and likely to be removed in the next version and that Tridion recommend that the code is rewritten to use the core Service.  However, the client is likely to rewrite this code in about six months anyway (with the introduction of some new business rules) and just wants to migrate it 'as is' during the upgrade.

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one known issue for it: If you are sending requests using UTF-16 you will need a hotfix, otherwise everything remains the same

Comment: That is good to know, although I would recommend migrating your code to use the Core Service as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks 978511.  I will make sure that I check the encoding before deploying.
Chris - I full agree with you you and will be getting this (and a couple of custom pages) changed to use the Core Service ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the Business Connector being deprecated (it still works fine btw) the only other thing to be aware of is the addition of some new (optional) elements in the various XML formats. If your XML handling is written well, no changes should be needed. If you depend on the exact XML structure, you might have to add the new elements into your XML templates.

The new element that I'm most aware of is called ExtensionXml and appears on Schemas and Fields. The documentation has an example of [how ExtensionXml is used](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_39147877CFF9415D9E5DDFEE101B0750) (with the Core Service, but it might be a good example for when you want to set them using the Business Connector too).

Comment: Thanks Frank.  The XML parsing appears to be written quite well so we shouldn't get a problem with this hopefully.  I will make sure to add it to the test script though!